# Cassandra: Finding partition keys

Tags: cassandra, nodetool, cassandra-3.0

We are currently testing Cassandra with the following table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE coreglead_v2.stats_by_site_user (
    d_tally text, -- ex.: '2016-01', '2016-02', etc..
    site_id int,
    d_date timestamp,
    site_user_id int,
    accepted counter,
    error counter,
    impressions_negative counter,
    impressions_positive counter,
    rejected counter,
    revenue counter,
    reversals_rejected counter,
    reversals_revenue counter,
    PRIMARY KEY (d_tally, site_id, d_date, site_user_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (site_id ASC, d_date ASC, site_user_id ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

For our test purposes, we have written a python script that randomises data across the 2016 calendar (12 months in total), we expect our partition key to be the **d_tally** column, at the same time, we expect our number of keys to be 12 (from '2016-01' to '2016-12').

Running nodetool cfstats is showing us the following though:

```
Table: stats_by_site_user
        SSTable count: 4
        Space used (live): 131977793
        Space used (total): 131977793
        Space used by snapshots (total): 0
        Off heap memory used (total): 89116
        SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.18667406304929424
        Number of keys (estimate): 24
        Memtable cell count: 120353
        Memtable data size: 23228804
        Memtable off heap memory used: 0
        Memtable switch count: 10
        Local read count: 169
        Local read latency: 1.938 ms
        Local write count: 4912464
        Local write latency: 0.066 ms
        Pending flushes: 0
        Bloom filter false positives: 0
        Bloom filter false ratio: 0.00000
        Bloom filter space used: 128
        Bloom filter off heap memory used: 96
        Index summary off heap memory used: 76
        Compression metadata off heap memory used: 88944
        Compacted partition minimum bytes: 5839589
        Compacted partition maximum bytes: 43388628
        Compacted partition mean bytes: 16102786
        Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): 102.91627247589237
        Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 103
        Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 1.0
        Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 1
```

What is confusing us is the "Number of keys (estimate): 24" part. Looking at our schema and assuming our test data (over 5 million writes) is made up of just 2016 data, where does the 24 keys estimate come from?

Here is an example of our data:

```
d_tally | site_id | d_date                   | site_user_id | accepted | error | impressions_negative | impressions_positive | rejected | revenue | reversals_rejected | reversals_revenue
---------+---------+--------------------------+--------------+----------+-------+----------------------+----------------------+----------+---------+--------------------+-------------------
 2016-01 |       1 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00+0000 |       240054 |        1 |  null |                 null |                    1 |     null |     553 |               null |              null
 2016-01 |       1 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00+0000 |      1263968 |        1 |  null |                 null |                    1 |     null |    1093 |               null |              null
 2016-01 |       1 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00+0000 |      1267841 |        1 |  null |                 null |                    1 |     null |     861 |               null |              null
 2016-01 |       1 | 2016-01-01 00:00:00+0000 |      1728725 |        1 |  null |                 null |                    1 |     null |     425 |               null |              null
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27963951/understanding-number-of-keys-in-nodetool-cfstats

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of keys is an estimate (although should be very close). It takes a sketch of the data from each sstable, and merges it together to estimate the cardinality ([hyperloglog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperLogLog)).

Unfortunately the equivalent does not exist in the memtable so it adds the cardinality of the memtable to the sstable estimate. This means things in both memtables and sstables are double counted. This is why you see `24` instead of `12`.